# clone from github but when i make upload image, directory not to storage/public but C:\xampp\tmp

Tags: php, laravel, image, upload, laravel-9

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TW0vG.png)

here's my code below

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $validateData = $request->validate([
        'pembelian_id' => '',
        'pconfirm_pic' => 'image|file|max:5087'
    ]);

    // $validatedData['pconfirm_pic'] = $request->file('pconfirm_pic')->store('payment_confirmation','public');
    
    
    
    
    Payconfirm::create($validateData);
    return redirect('/user/purchase/?status_pembayaran=1');
}
```

match with path where controller store to

Answer (score 0):

Run below artisan command

```
php artisan storage:link
```

[Read More About](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#the-public-disk)